# UITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths performing animation when it shouldn't

Tags: uitableview, ios

I'm using a UITableView in my iOS app, and have been seeing a strange issue recently.

Suppose my table is structured as follows:

```
section 1 header
row 
section 2 header
section 3 header
row
row 
...
```

(Note that section 2 has no rows)

I'm performing updates to the rows in my table via

```
    [self.tv beginUpdates];
    [self.tv reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:ip withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tv endUpdates];
```

I don't want any animations taking place. I just want the row to update. The issue is that this strategy works for *every* row and section in the my table *except* section 3, row 1: the first row of the last section. When I update this row (which is indeed using the correct indexPaths), rather than get no animation, the row does this little jump, like it's sliding in a new row to replace the old one or something. The row slides up ever so slightly, then back down, as if I was inserting a row. I'm guessing it has something to do with the header calculations, but I do return correct values for heightForHeaderInSection.

Has anyone seen this behavior?

Comment: I'm seeing this too, in iOS5. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I never found a solution, no.

Comment: Still having the same issue on iOS 7. Do you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the beginUpdates and endUpdates are necessary in this reload only scenario.

Comment: Have you tried changing the withRowAnimation param to check that it a least animate the way you ask when you do ?

Comment: Well, it actually doesn't animate the way I'm telling it to. It always does the little jump regardless of which animation I specify. Does that mean anything?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. The solution was to fetch the cell from the table using:

`UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]`

and then refresh it manually using a custom setup method or by simply calling:

`[cell setNeedsLayout]`

For more info, see:

[UITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths graphical glitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345802/uitableview-reloadrowsatindexpaths-graphical-glitch?rq=1)

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. In NSFetchedResultsChangeMove I'm trying to update the cell as well as calling moveRowAtIndexPath.